# Simple online key-value storage service

Tags: web-services, storage

In a number of projects I plan to create (widgets/local client software) I want to store some user preferences etc. I could do this client side, the widgets have this functionality, or I could store it online somewhere, giving the user access to those preferences on any computer, or after a reinstall etc..

The problem is that I don't want to associate those widgets etc with any domain in my possession, or pay the money for another domain and hosting, also implement and maintain the server side code for such a service.

So my question is: Is there any online services that provide storage for simple key-value pairs? Preferably free of course for limited usage. Keep in mind that I want to access it with javascript.

Comment: You can use keyvalue.xyz. It is cloud key/value store service with REST API.

Disclaimer: I have developed the system.

Comment: my keys got waked there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[OpenKeyval](http://openkeyval.org/) seems like just what you want.

> OpenKeyval is a completely open
>   key-value data store, exposed as a
>   drop-dead simple web service. The goal
>   is to make this a very easy way to
>   persist data in web applications.

You can set and retrieve data using jsonp, so you don't need to worry about cross domain request restrictions. Using it is as simple as:

**Storing a value:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.openkeyval.org/store/",
  data: "mykey=mydata",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    alert("Saved "+data);
  }
});
```

**Retrieving a value:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://api.openkeyval.org/mykey",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: open key val is down and no longer works :-/

Comment: I was in similar need and developed one for myself and hosted for public use. [online free key value store](http://keyvalue.immanuel.co/)

Comment: You can use keyvalue.xyz. It is cloud key/value store service with REST API. Disclaimer: I have developed the system.

Comment: Looks like the site is gone. https://www.meeiot.org looks new.

Comment: https://put.meeiot.org/5ba8e5788973226b3255844b37221c2a0f8a3921784b8cf1c93b9f/mykey=myvalue

https://get.meeiot.org/5ba8e5788973226b3255844b37221c2a0f8a3921784b8cf1c93b9f

also has queues

https://push.meeiot.org/5ba8e5788973226b3255844b37221c2a0f8a3921784b8cf1c93b9f/queue=value

https://pop.meeiot.org/5ba8e5788973226b3255844b37221c2a0f8a3921784b8cf1c93b9f

also has REST HTTP_POST (attachment multipart-data / json ) and custom return specifing headers

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could use [Google App Engine](https://appengine.google.com/), which has a great database system, and store everything in there.

Depending on how big your application is, you will have no storage limit, and it's a service that's always available and 100%* (if your application is not huge and uses loads of bandwidth) free.

You can use Java, Python or Ruby in there. so there's loads of nice options.

Comment: meeiot org is up and new